# Suppose I apply a force to a ball that can then only be slowed down by gravity or, perhaps, relativity. What happens to the ball? What would I see?

Tags: general-relativity, acceleration

Suppose I'm on planet Earth. I have a ball that, once set in motion, can only be slowed down or stopped by gravity. What will happen to this ball? What would I (an observer on Earth) see?

Here's what I think: at some point, that ball will reach escape velocity. It will hit at least a star/planet or two, and things may get more and more relativistic as the ball approaches the speed of light unless the gravity pull from another planet or star slows it down. Its relativistic mass will increase to the point where it is no longer able to accelerate any further, at which point it may slow down and come to a halt.

Comment: Why will it necessarily hit reach escape velocity? If there aren't any other forces, then the only way it can accelerate is via gravity - which will most likely just make it fall back to Earth.

Comment: it seems very logical

Comment: My guess is that you mean for this force to be applied continuously to the ball; if so, please edit your question to make this clearer.

Comment: @DanielGriscom What I mean is, once this ball starts accelerating at a given rate, it will keep accelerating at that same rate unless gravity or, perhaps, relativity, dictates that it should do otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I'm on planet Earth. I have a ball that, once set in motion, can only be slowed down or stopped by gravity. What will happen to this ball? What would I (an observer on Earth) see?
>   Here's what I think: at some point, that ball will reach escape velocity.

It appears you believe that if somebody throw a ball to the sky from the surface of an earth without atmosphere the ball will speed up as getting higher and higher till the ball reaches the speed of light.
This is not the case. The ball will fall quickly back on earth.

Answer (score 0):

the ball wouldn't come to the halt as its mass goes on increasing it would simply stop accelerating and keep on moving at the uniform motion close to the speed of light which is determined by how much force u had applied. of course it would be impossible to travel in speed of light as it would require infinite energy.

Comment: Mass does not increase relativistically, momentum and kinetic energy do. Look up 'relativistic mass'.

Comment: @Gert yeah you are rite

Answer (score 0):

> Its relativistic mass will increase to the point where it is no longer
>   able to accelerate any further, at which point it may slow down and
>   come to a halt.

I'll assume the ball has a fictional mechanism attached that gives a constant propulsive force, forever. In that case, yes, its energy (and hence relativistic mass) will increase as its speed increases. Hence acceleration will gradually decrease. However, as its mass will never become infinite, its acceleration will never reach zero, and the speed will always continue to increase - albeit at a slower and slower rate. It will get closer and closer to $c$, the speed of light.

Gravity from all stars (and planets) will bend the ball's path, continuously. The amount of bending depends on the speed of the ball at the time, and how close it gets to each star/planet. But it is unlikely that the ball will ever hit a star (and certainly not "or two", as just one collision will destroy it). Photons travel for billions of years without ever hitting a star - that's how we can see far away galaxies.